# Terraform intrpolation to access attribute of all resources of given type

Tags: terraform

Terraform allows for easy interpolation of resource attributes when they are created with `count = N` like :

```
${resource.name.*.attr[X]}
```

What I would like is to access the attribute for all resources of this type regardless of it's name. Something like

```
${resource.*.*.attr[X]}
```

would do, but terraform does not seem to support this kind of notation. Any idea if/how this can be done ?

Comment: Nope, it can't be done. I think this might be a duplicate but can't find it right now. Do you have a use case you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: yep, I have a whole bunch of openstack vm's launched in multiple groups with count=N and I would like to add all of them to acl of storage backend in one go, avoiding adding acl as many times as many groups I have in terraform.

Comment: If you switch to from count to a for_each (tf 0.12+), you should be able to loop over the single map of resources to add it to the acl.